# Need help finding general formula for an iterative equation.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recursion

If we have a iterative equation defined as

for $i=1:n$ $$a=a(4-a),$$ I need help finding the general formula for this in terms of n. I know some obvious ones like,
$$n=1\quad\quad a=4a-a^2$$
$$n=2 \quad\quad a=4(a(4-a))-(a(4-a))^2.$$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1}=a_n(4-a_n)$$
$$a_{n+1}=4a_n-a_n^2$$
$$-a_{n+1}=-4a_n+a_n^2$$
$$4-a_{n+1}=4-4a_n+a_n^2=(2-a_n)^2$$
$$2-a_{n+1}=(2-a_n)^2-2$$

So we get
$$2-a_{n+1}=(2-a_n)^2-2=\{(2-a_{n-1})^2-2\}^2-2= \ldots =[\ldots \{(2-a_1)^2-2\}^2 \dots \text{(n brackets)}\ldots ]^2 -2 $$

If $a_1$ is given, then the recursive formula is this:
$$a_{n+1}=4-[\ldots \{(2-a_1)^2-2\}^2 \dots \text{(n brackets)}\ldots ]^2 $$

However, if $a_0$ is given instead of $a_1$, we will have to go one step further.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. I understand that I now have for example,$$a_4=4-((((2-a_0)^2-2)^2-2)^2-2)^2,$$  I now need to work out a general formula for this.

Comment: You're welcome.. :-)